# Undefined index in include

Tags: php

I am receive the following error **Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in include()** but have I not defined the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`

```
function get_browser_name($user_agent)
{
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'Opera') || strpos($user_agent, 'OPR/')) return 'Opera';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Edge')) return 'Edge';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome')) return 'Chrome';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Safari')) return 'Safari';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Firefox')) return 'Firefox';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'MSIE') || strpos($user_agent, 'Trident/7')) return 'Explorer';
    return 'Other';
}
```

Error is on this line:

```
<body class="<?php echo get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);?>" <?php print $attributes;?> <?php print $classes; ?>>
```

Comment: The code works when not used as an include? The header might not be set.

Comment: But you are passing `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: Maybe if you showed us the COMPLETE error message and identified the line number on the error message against the code you show us, we could help

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is the complete error, the remain page is just the file location and line number. the line number points to the body class line

Comment: Exactly. So which line of the code you show us is the line mentioned in the error message please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated my question to show when piece of code had the error. Since the error was line 79 and non related code above it needed (a header close tag) I just posted the exact line. I apologize for that.

Answer (score -1):

Reference by http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125

```
function get_browser_name($user_agent)
{
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'Opera') || strpos($user_agent, 'OPR/')) return 'Opera';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Edge')) return 'Edge';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome')) return 'Chrome';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Safari')) return 'Safari';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Firefox')) return 'Firefox';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'MSIE') || strpos($user_agent, 'Trident/7')) return 'Internet Explorer';

    return 'Other';
}

// Usage:

echo get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Comment: A **good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. and maybe even upvote it if it solves there issue

Comment: Now its a link only answer